# Javascript to JSON splice location

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, push, splice

We are sending a value from javascript to a json file — that works; the value is put into the wrong location of the json file though.

`[{"sphereposition":[]}]`

When we tried, it either got added before or after the whole "sphere position" part — we want to number to be sent within the [] of "spehereposition", though.

Here's our code:

```
app.post('/store-data', async (req, res) => {
    const xcoord = req.body

    var fs = require('fs')
    
    fs.readFile('./answers.json', function ( err, data ) {
        if (err) throw err;
        
        var json = JSON.parse( data );
        json.push( 0, 0, xcoord );
        json = JSON.stringify( json );
        
        fs.writeFile( './answers.json', json, function( err ) {
            if (err) throw err;
            
            return json;
        } );
    } );
})
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "*we want to number to be sent within the [] of "spehereposition"*" - then you need to use `json[0].sphereposition.push( 0, 0, xcoord );`

Answer (score 0):

To get the values inserted in the nested array, you should address that property:

```
    json[0].sphereposition.push( 0, 0, xcoord );
    //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

As a side note: don't call that variable `json`, as it is actually an array object, not a JSON string. When you overwrite it with the stringified version, then it becomes a JSON string. But it is better practice to use a separate variable for that:

```
    var arr = JSON.parse( data );
    arr[0].sphereposition.push( 0, 0, xcoord );
    var json = JSON.stringify( arr );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, we tried that and had this error: 
json[0].sphereposition.push( 0, 0, xcoord );
                ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sphereposition' of undefined

What could cause this?

Comment: It means that your `json` variable is not an array, so it is not `[{"sphereposition":[]}]` as depicted in your question. Use `console.log` or inspection to verify what the exact value of `data` is right before this error occurs.